# Scheme url sometimes don't open a new intent (deep linking)

Tags: android

I have a custom scheme being parsed and accepted in the app. 
Most of the times there isn't any issue it, creates a Main Activity, and everything is just as expected.

But, just sometimes, it simple reopens the existent Activity, in this case it's just like a simple recover from background, there is no new intent or anything else.

Did anyone has this problem? Any tip for catching url scheme arguments for this case, where no new intent is created? I hardly can reproduce this problem, but happens a lot to my client.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="xxxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The deep linking is supposed to start your intent, but if it's already started it won't call the onCreate method (assuming you have the parsing stuff in that method), thus it won't call the parsing stuff.If not then it will still fail since you are checking for the intent data, which is the data of the intent that started the activity, if the activity was opened, then it wasn't called by your link, so it does not have the data. That's why it only works when you kill the app and press the link.